# Where is it documented how to write a git remote helper?

Tags: git, github

I've googled this topic with every search-phrase I can think of - and seem to find everything that could possibly match the search-phrase *except* for an answer to this question. Is there documentation anywhere on how to write a remote helper for Git?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much documentation except:

- [`Documentation/git-remote-testgit.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/398dd4bd039680ba98497fbedffa415a43583c16/Documentation/git-remote-testgit.txt), followed by 2 examples:
- [`git-remote-testgit.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/398dd4bd039680ba98497fbedffa415a43583c16/git-remote-testgit.sh)
- [`remote-testsvn.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/398dd4bd039680ba98497fbedffa415a43583c16/remote-testsvn.c)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of code explained on APriorIt:

https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/715-virtualization-git-remote-helper#q2